# Visual Studio скругленные края TextBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Как закруглить края у TextBox?

Comment: Переопределить шаблон.

Comment: Как переделать? Спасите новичка :)

Comment: Сейчас напишу, подождите :)

Comment: Готово, пробуйте.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Есть несколько путей.

Правильный путь — вы можете переопределить шаблон/стиль. Это делается так на Visual Studio 2015. Я делаю для WPF, но для UWP должно быть по идее то же самое. (В более старых версиях Visual Studio вытащить стиль было невозможно, и приходилось использовать Expression Blend, или искать в документации.)

Более простой путь, без шаблона, с ручным созданием лэйаута внизу.

---

Для начала, заведите где-нибудь обыкновенный `TextBox`. Перейдите в визуальный дизайнер, и откройте меню:

[image: открываем меню]

Выберите в меню «редактировать шаблон»:

[image: редактировать шаблон]

Ради бога, не оставляйте имя по умолчанию `TextBoxStyle1`!

Вам откроется текущий стиль, который определяет, как выглядит `TextBox`. Он будет определён либо в ресурсах текущего окна, либо всего приложения, как вы уж выберете. Найдите в стиле переопределение template'а, а в нём — `Border`:

[image: border найден]

Добавьте в `Border` какое-то значение `CornerRadius`:

```
<Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="7"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
</Border>
```

(не копируйте мой текст, а добавьте `CornerRadius` в то, что есть у вас!) Этот же стиль используйте для других текстбоксов. Или уберите у него `x:Key`, чтобы он относился ко всем текстбоксам вообще.

Пора запускать:

[image: что добился, что добился]

Готово!

Если хотите, значение радиуса закругления можно привязать к attached property.

---

Более простое решение — «выключить» границу у `TextBox`'а и положить сверху `Border`:

```
<Border CornerRadius="7" BorderBrush="#FFABADB3" BorderThickness="1"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True">
    <TextBox BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"/>
</Border>
```

Вам скорее всего не нужно `VerticalAlignment="Center"`, `UseLayoutRounding="True"` позволяет выглядеть шаблону не замыленным, `BorderBrush="#FFABADB3"` пришлось «стащить» из предыдущего решения, `Background="Transparent"` и `Border` нужно, чтобы `TextBox` не перекрывал закруглённые углы.

Comment: Вау.... Огромное спасибо, что уделили мне столько времени) Очень полезная информация! Пойду попробую

Comment: @Denisok: Пожалуйста! Буду рад, если помогло.

Comment: А сделать эффект тени(чтобы текстбоксы "летали" над страницей) делается также в визуальном дизайнере?

Comment: @Denisok: Например, так: http://pastebin.com/Mj9crJAv

Comment: @Denisok: Или так: http://pastebin.com/gxhhyq1r (текст выходит чётче)