# Как в ToolBar изменить цвет правой полосы?

Tags: c#, wpf, toolbar

Как в ToolBar изменить цвет правой полосы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В предложенном https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa970772(v=vs.85).aspx типа не соответствует ToolBar (`TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">`).

Если его заменить в предложенном ToolBarOverflowButtonStyle https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa970772(v=vs.85).aspx
 на {x:Type ToolBar}" то программа не запускается.

Если сделять так то угол не изменится. Но программа  при этом работает:

```
<ToolBar Name="toolbar1" DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                     Style="{DynamicResource AAA}"

                >
```

.

```
<Style x:Key="AAA" TargetType="{x:Type ToolBar}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF0F0F0F" />
    </Style>
```

Но если добавить:

```
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"
```

После этого панель не отображается. Если к ней добавить высоту то она будет пустой без кнопок.

```
<Style x:Key="ToolBarOverflowButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToolBar}">
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolBar}">
        <Border Name="Bd"
          CornerRadius="0,3,3,0"
          Background="Transparent"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
          <Grid>
            <Path Name="Arrow"
              Fill="Black"
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
              Margin="2,3"
              Data="M -0.5 3 L 5.5 3 L 2.5 6 Z"/>
            <ContentPresenter/>
          </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush}"/>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush}"/>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush}"/>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="#AAA"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: А покажите весь ваш стиль.

Comment: AAA - это весь стиль. Или полностью `<ToolBar Name="toolbar1" DockPanel.Dock="Top"` показать?

Comment: Ага, понял. Нет, эту часть так просто стилизовать не выйдет. Смотрите решение в ответе (да, оно достаточно громоздкое).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего, наверное, заставить Visual Studio сгенерировать для вас стиль с шаблоном.

Как это делать, описано [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/540316/10105). Имея шаблон, вы находите в нём код, отображающий ваш визуальный элемент. (Это легко сделать: когда вы выделяете элемент в исходном коде, соответствующий визуальный элемент подсвечивается в дизайнере.)

На моей машине это такой элемент:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="OverflowButton" ClickMode="Press" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
              IsChecked="{Binding IsOverflowOpen, Mode=TwoWay,
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
              IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding HasOverflowItems}"
              Style="{StaticResource ToolBarHorizontalOverflowButtonStyle}"/>
```

(я немного переформатировал для лучшего отображения).

Мы видим, что за визуальное оформление отвечает стиль `ToolBarHorizontalOverflowButtonStyle`. Находим его:

```
<Style x:Key="ToolBarHorizontalOverflowButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ToolBarToggleButtonHorizontalBackground}"/>
```

и сразу над ним

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToolBarToggleButtonHorizontalBackground" Color="#FFEEF5FD"/>
```

Меняем на

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToolBarToggleButtonHorizontalBackground" Color="Red"/>
```

и получаем:

[image: иллюстрация]