# Стилизация ComboBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf

Добрый день, столкнулся со следующей проблемкой. Не получается задать прозрачность ComboBoxItem. Подскажите как можно это сделать.

На данный момент пробую вот так:

```
<ComboBox
  Style="{StaticResource regInputStyle}"
  x:Name="point">
    <ComboBoxItem Padding="5" Background="White" Opacity="0.8" Content="Один"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Padding="5" Background="White" Opacity="0.8" Content="Два"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Придётся изменять шаблон, вот [пример](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22696386/692829)

Answer (score 2):

Это, к сожалению, не так просто. Давайте делать это по частям.

Во-первых, у выпадающего списка комбобокса есть свой цвет фона и цвет границы. Эти цвета берутся как ресурсы с ключами `SystemColors.WindowBrushKey` и `SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey`, поэтому их можно превратить в прозрачные, если хочется.

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}">
            Transparent
        </SolidColorBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}">
            Transparent
        </SolidColorBrush>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBoxItem Padding="5" Background="White" Opacity="0.8" Content="Один"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Padding="5" Background="White" Opacity="0.8" Content="Два"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Это даёт почти то, что надо, но именно почти.

[image: комбобокс, что ж ещё?]

Видите, в чём проблема? Системный стиль для комбобокса определяет *тень*, и мы её нашей прозрачностью не отключили. Если вас такой результат устраивает, на этом всё. Если нет, читайте дальше.

Как её можно отключить? Для это я не нашёл встроенных средств, и значит, придётся доставать серьёзное оружие — редактировать шаблон. Если у вас Visual Studio 2015 или выше, вы можете легко получить системный шаблон на редактирование, если нет — вам может помочь Expression Blend (или друг, у которого установлена Visual Studio 2015 или старше).

Как попросить Visual Studio показать вам стиль, написано в подробностях [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/540316/10105). Имея стиль, вы должны найти элемент, который задаёт тень. У меня это такой код:

```
<Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen=...>
    <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" ...>
        <Border x:Name="dropDownBorder"
                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                ...
```

Мы видим, что тень задаётся контролом `<Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome .../>`, но цвет его установлен в `Transparent`. Поискав ещё по коду шаблона, находим триггер, который меняет цвет на непрозрачный:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="shadow" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
        <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="shadow" Value="#71000000"/>
    </Trigger>
```

Закомментировав этот триггер (у меня он встречается в коде шаблона дважды), получаем нужный результат:

[image: ну и ещё один комбобокс]

---

Недостаток «бронебойного» метода с переопределением шаблона — вы фиксируете шаблон, подходящий для той операционной системы, на которой вы это делаете. Например, если вы делаете это на Windows 10, внешний вид комбобокса будет как в Windows 10, даже если вы запустите программу на Windows 7. Обычно это не большая проблема, потому что вы меняете стиль полностью.