# C# WPF Изменить background списка menu item?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как изменить background цвет выпадающего списка menu item? Если поставить background для menu item закрасится только прямоугольник, мне нужно закрасить зону где margin. Для самого прямоугольника меню изменить цвет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Foreground="White" Background="#FF505050">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="_Open" Background="DimGray"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Close"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Save"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <StackPanel/>
 </DockPanel>
```

Comment: Покажите код, скрин того что получается и скрин того что вы хотите получить

Comment: Придется править шаблон

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите, к сожалению, прямого интерфейса к этому нет, так что вам придётся редактировать шаблон `MenuItem`'а. Как это сделано, описано, например, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/540316/10105).

У меня искомые куски часть (внутри `PART_Popup`) выглядят так:

```
<Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="#FF959595" BorderThickness="1" Background="WhiteSmoke">
```

и

```
<Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="WhiteSmoke" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
```

Поменяв `WhiteSmoke` на искомый цвет (и убрав `<Rectangle Fill="`, следующие за `OpaqueRect`), получается то, что надо:

[image: Тёмочка плачет горючими слезами]